# What does "// TODO Auto Generated method stub" mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

I see it all the time and can't find a simple description.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It means that your IDE (or some other tool) has automatically generated a method for you, but has left the body blank to be filled in by you (this is known as a "[stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub)").

In your case, it was probably Eclipse.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can prevent these by unchecking the option to auto-generate constructors/desctructors in the 'new class' wizard.

Comment: You can also make your own TODO comments as a reminder of something that you need to implement or modify at a later stage

Answer (score 10):

This is a comment that's added by Eclipse (an IDE) when you have eclipse create a method body for you. It's meant as a reminder for the programmer that he/she needs to code something in the method

Answer (score 3):

These stubs mean that they are inherited abstract methods from super class whose implementations need to be crammed by you.